# Add Protractor E2E test code coverage to SonarQube

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, sonarqube, protractor, code-coverage

I'd like **Protractor** E2E tests to reflect  my code coverage in **SonarQube**.

I've tried **grunt-protractor-coverage** npm module but it shows 100% coverage while the report file it creates is empty.

Here's the relevant part of my Gruntfile.js:

```
connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            runtime: {
                options: {
                    base: 'instrumented/build'
                }
            }
        },
        instrument: {
            files: 'build/**/*.js',
            options: {
                lazy: true,
                basePath: "instrumented"
            }
        },
        protractor_coverage: {
            options: {
                keepAlive: true,
                noColor: false,
                coverageDir: 'coverage',
                args: {
                    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000'
                }
            },
            local: {
                options: {
                    configFile: './protractor-chrome-conf.js'
                }
            }
        },
        makeReport: {
            src: 'coverage/*.json',
            options: {
                type: 'lcov',
                dir: 'coverage/dir',
                print: 'detail'
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you get this working, and if so, do you think the protractor reporting is giving you anything valuable? Our protractor coverage report doesn't seem too helpful and I'm wondering if it's something we have misconfigured, or if the report generation doesn't do a good job of detecting what's covered.

Comment: Nevermind, it was a configuration issue and we do see good reporting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first install the [SonarJS code analyzer](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJS)

And then this plugin can be fed with a LCOV report providing the coverage information: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import